# Generate uniformly distributed random number in Nginx?

Tags: c, nginx, random

Nginx seems to have a built-in function called `ngx_random` that's used in [various places](http://lxr.nginx.org/ident?_i=ngx_random) of the source code. But it seems just to be defined as:`#define ngx_random random`

If I'm understanding this correctly, that means all the places Nginx calling `ngx_random()` it's just calling (on Linux platform) [random()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random). From the [doc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random) it isn't clear to me that it is guaranteed uniform distribution with a given range in any way, and I'm suspecting that similar to rand(), it's [not uniform at all](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful), and will only be uniform if range `n` is divisible by `RAND_MAX`.

But the nice thing of using `ngx_random` is I believe the system takes care of the seeding automatically, during startup time. Whereas if I want to use something truly uniform with my range, like [drand48](https://linux.die.net/man/3/drand48), I believe will have to add a new line after the following in [ngx_posix_init.c](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/os/unix/ngx_posix_init.c#0082)?

```
srandom(((unsigned) ngx_pid << 16) ^ tp->sec ^ tp->msec);
srand48(((unsigned) ngx_pid << 16) ^ tp->sec ^ tp->msec); //Added so that I can use drand48
```

So is my assumption on `ngx_random` correct? And if I want to use `drand48` in any place of the various modules, is the above the only way doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it myself with nginx, so consider it just an idea. On Linux (or similar ELF based systems, e.g. Solaris) you could, using LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD trick, to replace and/or intercept weak symbols from standard C library. It is often used to intercept and/or replace malloc, but might work for you as well

Code sample (untested, not compiled, just to demonstrate an idea)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void (*real_srandom)(uint32_t) = NULL;

static void srandom_init(void) {
    real_srandom = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "srandom");
    if (NULL == real_srandom) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in `dlsym`: %s\n", dlerror());
    }
}

void srandom(uint32_t seed) {
    if(real_srandom == NULL) {
        srandom_init();
    }

    real_srandom(seed);
    srand48(seed);
}
```

You could write SO to replace calls to random(3) as well, replacing it with your own implementation. The only thing you cannot replace is RAND_MAX, as it is compiled in constant.

I would be happy to hear if this trick works for you or not

Comment: Thanks! This is an interesting idea. Unfortunately I cannot replace all random() or srandom() function across my whole nginx image --- most places in the source code use random() justifiably, it's just this doesn't fit my use case when I only wanted uniform distribution with a specified range. It doesn't look like much workaround available except I shall just explicitly seed srand48 in ngx_posix_init.c, and then use drand48() when I need it...

Comment: @Superziyi well, you could just chain them as I showed. Chaining might be safest option because it is guaranteed you won't miss any srandom() call. Anyway, good luck

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now...thanks very much, will try it out!